# Slow CREATE TABLE AS followed by SELECT (other solutions haven't worked)

Tags: mariadb-10.5

I have a problem which is similar to [Slow CREATE table from subquery using SELECT .. INNER JOIN](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/165248/slow-create-table-from-subquery-using-select-inner-join) but the solutions provided there have not made any difference for me.

I'm using MariaDB 15.1 and have tried this on 2 separate physical machines. One is a production web server (4 GHz, 8 core Xeon with 32 GB RAM and a production grade SSD). The other is my 2021 MacBook Pro (1.4 GHz 4 core Intel, 8 GB RAM, SSD). The performance on the queries doesn't significantly vary in either environment - they are too slow for our application to be considered usable.

Our web application allows users to search for chemical substances which are mapped to 1 or more filters. I have eliminated the web application - which is built in PHP - as being the bottleneck. All queries below have been run directly on the database.

If I run this query:

```
SELECT s.id 
FROM substances s 
WHERE ( exists ( SELECT null 
                 FROM filters_substances fs 
                 WHERE fs.substance_id = s.id 
                 AND fs.filter_id = 2676
                 ) 
     OR exists ( SELECT null 
                 FROM filters_substances fs 
                 WHERE fs.substance_id = s.id 
                 AND fs.filter_id = 2677
                 )  
     OR exists ( SELECT null 
                 FROM filters_substances fs 
                 WHERE fs.substance_id = s.id 
                 AND fs.filter_id = 2678
                 )
       );
```

This takes approx 0.1 seconds to execute and returns 3 rows. This is fine and I wouldn't expect it to execute quicker than this.

We need to write the data returned by that `SELECT` to another table for the logged-in user of our application. We do this by wrapping the SQL above inside a `CREATE TABLE AS` statement:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tmpdata.filtering_1234 AS 
SELECT s.id FROM substances s WHERE 
( 
    ...
);
```

This creates a table on a separate database (always hosted on the same machine) called `tmpdata` where the table is named "filtering_1234". The suffix, "_1234", is the logged in user's ID.

Although the query above executes successfully it takes approx 3 - 4 seconds. If more filters (`fs.filter_id =` ) or conditions are added it can take longer, to the point where the web application appears to be un-usable.

The `CREATE TABLE` statement *on it's own* executes in approx 0.1 seconds:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tmpdata.filtering_1234(id INT);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.13 sec)
```

I tried adding the `(id INT)` part of the statement above to the full query:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tmpdata.filtering_1234(id INT) AS
SELECT ( ... )
```

The `id` column in this case corresponds to the primary key of a table `substances` where the substances are selected from as per `SELECT s.id FROM substances s`.

I tried adding a separate auto-incrementing primary key - called `pk` - to the table, as well as the `id` column for storing the data returned by the select statement:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tmpdata.filtering_1234(pk int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, id INT, PRIMARY KEY(pk))
```

Again this runs in a similar 3 - 4 seconds.

In all cases we get the correct results, i.e. the same 3 substances are always written to `filtering_1234`.

How can I debug this further to find where the bottleneck is?

The structure of my tables where the data comes from are:

```
mariadb> DESCRIBE substances;
+-------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type                  | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | mediumint(8) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| app_id      | varchar(8)            | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
| name        | varchar(1500)         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| date        | date                  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
4 rows in set (0.01 sec)
 
mariadb> DESCRIBE filters_substances;
+--------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type                  | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id           | mediumint(8) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| substance_id | mediumint(8) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| filter_id    | smallint(5) unsigned  | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+--------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mariadb> SHOW INDEXES FROM substances;
+------------+------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+
| Table      | Non_unique | Key_name    | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment | Ignored |
+------------+------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+
| substances |          0 | PRIMARY     |            1 | id          | A         |      288989 | NULL     | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               | NO      |
| substances |          0 | app_id      |            1 | app_id | A         |      288989 | NULL     | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               | NO      |
+------------+------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
 
mariadb> SHOW INDEXES from filters_substances;
+--------------------+------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+
| Table              | Non_unique | Key_name     | Seq_in_index | Column_name  | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment | Ignored |
+--------------------+------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+
| filters_substances |          0 | PRIMARY      |            1 | id           | A         |     1626686 | NULL     | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               | NO      |
| filters_substances |          1 | substance_id |            1 | substance_id | A         |      813343 | NULL     | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               | NO      |
| filters_substances |          1 | filter_id    |            1 | filter_id    | A         |       70725 | NULL     | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               | NO      |
+--------------------+------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`EXPLAIN`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/explain/) command to "debug" i.e. show the query execution plan. Or even the [`ANALYZE`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/analyze-statement/) command which will actually run the query and give you some additional stats. You can use [`FORMAT=JSON`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/explain-format-json/) with both commands if you prefer to read JSON format, and I think it also can give additional information.

Your `SELECT` query can probably be optimised by rewriting it to replace `OR` with `UNION ALL` as otherwise I don't think it can't make use of all the indexes. (Use `UNION DISTINCT` to remove duplicate rows.) Something like:

```
SELECT s.id 
FROM substances s 
    JOIN filters_substances fs ON s.id = fs.substance_id
WHERE fs.filter_id = 2676
UNION 
SELECT s.id 
FROM substances s 
    JOIN filters_substances fs ON s.id = fs.substance_id
WHERE fs.filter_id = 2677
UNION 
SELECT s.id 
FROM substances s 
    JOIN filters_substances fs ON s.id = fs.substance_id
WHERE fs.filter_id = 2678;
```

You should also replace your individual indexes in the `filters_substances` table with a composite index on `(substance_id, filter_id)` as a single query can only make use of one index on a particular table (unless you join the same table multiple times). (I see a composite index was suggested in the answers to the other question you referenced as well - any reason why you can't use that?)

One reason why `CREATE TABLE ... AS SELECT ...` takes so much longer is of course that you are writing the data to disk as opposed to just outputting it. Also, creating a table means creating new files on disk.

The fact that your web application is creating a table as part of regular user operations (?) feels like an anti-pattern. Is there some other way you could achieve the same end result?